# PhoneGap: Catching any pages that fail to load

Tags: cordova, webview

We have some links inside our PhoneGap app and have configured these links to be shown within a webview.

How can we detect when the webview is showing an error, like page not found, unavailable, etc.? We just need a simple thing to redirect to an error page within the app so the user isn't left with a browser style page load error inside our 'app'.